# Trouble sending emails using Action mailer in rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I am having trouble sending emails via action mailer in rails 7 app. Now If I configure my action mailer using gmail, it works fine and sends emails as expected. The setting is following.

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: '3000' }
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default charset: 'utf-8'

 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
     address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
     port: 587,
     user_name: Rails.application.credentials.dig(:Email, :username),
     password:  Rails.application.credentials.dig(:Email, :password),
     authentication: 'plain'
   }
```

If I change this to other service than gmail, I do not receive emails in my inbox. I do see in logs that it sends email but it never arrives in the destination inbox. The setting is following

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: '3000' }
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default charset: 'utf-8'

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: 'mail.punjab.gov.pk',
  port: 25,
  user_name: Rails.application.credentials.dig(:Email, :username),
  password:  Rails.application.credentials.dig(:Email, :password),
  authentication: 'plain'
}
```

Comment: I suggest double-checking that the other service uses the same `authentication` method and doesn't require other additional configuration, for example `tls`. See the [Rails Guides about Action Mailer Configuration](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration). I also suggest checking your SPAM folder.

Comment: One potential issue here is that `Hash#dig` will simply return nil if the key cannot be found. Instead use methods that will raise an error if the key is not set so that you actually know if your application is configured properly at boot time like `fetch`. Also did you really mean to capitalize `:Email`?

Comment: Firstly, I have checked my spam, nothing is over there. @spickermann. Secondly Email is just a namespace in yml file (credentials.yml.enc). I have also tried by just giving values here in configuration instead of using Rails credentials.